Unexplained Disk Growth in Docker Swarm Node
I have a Swarm cluster with 5 nodes, running a variety of services.
I’ve noticed that one of the nodes is experiencing abnormal disk growth. My containers are mostly static, yet one server’s /var directory grows by approximately 1GB every 4 hours.

When the growth reaches about 15GB, I analyze /var using ncdu. No directory exceeds 2GB (inside /var/lib/docker/overlay2). Performing multiple ncdu scans at different intervals, I can’t identify any specific directory growing, even though df -h and my monitoring tools show the disk space continuing to increase.
After further investigation, I identified the problematic container, which I'll refer to as my_app. I executed a docker service update --force my_app to restart it on a different node. Immediately, 20GB of disk space was freed on the original node.
On the new node, the disk usage starts increasing again at the same rate of 1GB every 4 hours. The behavior of /var remains consistent: it appears stable and relatively static.
I connected to the container using docker exec -it /bin/sh my_app and checked its disk usage:
/data/app # du -sh /
538.3M  /

This size remains completely stable.
Here is the output of docker system df -v:
[root@my_node_04  ~] > docker system df -v
Images space usage:

REPOSITORY                                                TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE      SHARED SIZE   UNIQUE SIZE   CONTAINERS
my_image                  5a1213d7   0af202fa8b20   3 weeks ago    375MB     0B            374.9MB       1

Containers space usage:

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                              COMMAND                  LOCAL VOLUMES   SIZE      CREATED        STATUS                    NAMES
9e69c4863291   my_image:5a1213d7                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   0               123MB     5 hours ago    Up 5 hours                my_app.1.ptgimdvy081y48tbv2f8mjqvp


Local Volumes space usage:

VOLUME NAME   LINKS     SIZE

Build cache usage: 0B

CACHE ID   CACHE TYPE   SIZE      CREATED   LAST USED   USAGE     SHARED

Do you have any ideas about what could explain this disk growth? Are there any further investigations I could carry out to pinpoint the root cause?
Thanks in advance!

overlay2 stores the containers filesystem including the "diff" layer which captures changes that the container has written. It is growing because the container is writing files that it is not cleaning up. One thing docker does not unfortunately do is enforce disk space quota per container.

Actually, my overlay2 directory isn't growing. As of now, I've been using 16GB of disk space since yesterday, and my overlay directory has remained stable at a total of 8GB since then.
I suspect that my app might have a memory leak. Could this RAM leak explain the increase in disk space usage? The two growth curves look quite similar...
